# Calcular unidades de tiempo en C

Tags: c

alguna idea de como sumar horas. Ejemplo tengo en las variables

```
int hora = tm->tm_hour;
int min = tm->tm_min;
```

la hora actual y los minutos actuales, en un determinado momento necesito sumarle horas o minutos pero no se como obtener un resultado sin pasarme del formato de 24 hs

Comment: Has investigado algo? Por lo general se realizan preguntas con una investigación previa.

Comment: Explica con más detalle qué tipo de marca de tiempo necesitas como tu resultado. Necesitas otra variable de tipo `struct tm`?